# removeChild doesn't work when called from a timeout at page load

Tags: javascript

I've got a HTML div that is supposed to hold dynamically generated children. Said children are to be removed from the list after a set amount of time (e.g 1000 ms).

I've seen people having issues about the scope in a timeout function but I don't think that's it.

```
function pushAlert(type, text) {
    let newItem;

    // newItem gets generated here.

    alertList.innerHTML += newItem;

    setTimeout(() => {
        popAlert();
    }, 1000);

}

function popAlert(e) {
    if (e) {
        alertList.removeChild(e);
    } else {
        alertList.removeChild(alertList.firstChild); <!-- gets here but doesn't remove the child. console.log on alertList and alertList.firstChild displays the proper elements. -->
    }
}
```

pushAlert works every time.

popAlert works for times when pushAlert was called after page load.

```
<script src='../js/alerts.js'></script>
<script>
pushAlert('info', 'info');
</script>
```

If I call pushAlert like this, the timeout that is supposed to call popAlert works, but popAlert does not remove the child. But if I call pushAlert from the event of a form submit, everything works properly, including the timeout-ed popAlert.

EDIT: gif showing a visualization of the issue https://i.gyazo.com/aa3dc08af016450c7082482ec34a277c.mp4

Comment: Seems the pushAlert trigger when page did not fully loaded. Try to call pushAlert using window.onload=“pushAlert(‘info’,’info’)”

Comment: How is `alertList` originally created? [Does it contain whitespace?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild#Example)

Comment: @AllenChak The scripts are at the end of <body>, right before </body>.

Comment: @AuxTaco apparently that was it. I find it weird since the whitespace didn't interfere if I didn't call pushAlert from the <script> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild).

`.firstChild` will get first child which can be a [node of any type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType).

`.firstElementChild` will only get the first child which is a node of element type.

To illustrate, you can click the two buttons in the snippet below to see the response:

```js
firstChild.addEventListener('click', removeFirstChild);
firstElementChild.addEventListener('click', removeFirstElementChild);

function removeFirstChild(){
  alertList.removeChild(alertList.firstChild);
}

function removeFirstElementChild(){
  alertList.removeChild(alertList.firstElementChild);
}
```

```html
<div id="alertList">
  <p>This is paragraph 0.</p>
  <p>This is paragraph 1.</p>
  <p>This is paragraph 2.</p>
</div>

<button id="firstChild">firstChild</button>
<button id="firstElementChild">firstElementChild</button>
```